# how submit grails form with submit button ouside form tag

Tags: java, grails, gsp

Is it possible to submit a grails form () with submit button () outside that form. I know we can do the same in javascript for simple HTML page. I m relatively new to grails (gsp pages) having hard time knowing the new tags.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
 Amit

Comment: The name of the g:Form is also the "id" of form tag. You could use javascript "onclick" on your button to do form.submit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery to submit your form outside form tag as:

```
<button class="some-class" onclick="jQuery('#formId').submit()">Submit</button>
```

Enjoy programming..